# How to delete or hide multiple components on click with react/react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, dictionary

https://res.cloudinary.com/catify/image/upload/v1588704903/hcnqjp7okfykkb3az2v3.jpg

Hello im trying to create a proyect of a guessing game, i have multiple components of letters as show in the image, some letters are needed for the answer and some are not, i need a button that when i click it it removes or hides the components that are not needed for the answer, how can i do this with react or react native?

Im saving the letters in a array and then rendering them using Map with a custom component that is styled to look like the photo, im doing it in react native but i think it should be the same in react, any help is welcome, thanks.

```
  return (
    <Animated.View style={{flex: 1}}>
      {Letters.forEach(element => {
        <LetterCard letter={element} />;
      })}

      <Button
        title="eliminar"
        onPress={() => {
          eliminar;
        }}
      />
    </Animated.View>
  );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need a list in state or somewhere that holds which letters are needed and which aren't, as well as a boolean to determine if you are showing all letters or just your needed letters.

Your button which toggles to show/hide the unneeded letters would simply toggle the neededOnly state.

```
this.state={        
    neededLetters = [],   //array of needed letters
    neededOnly = false,
}

{neededOnly ? 
neededLetters.forEach(element => {
    <LetterCard letter={element} />;
}) : 
Letters.forEach(element => {
    <LetterCard letter={element} />;
})}


<Button
    title="eliminate"
    onPress={() => {
      this.setState(prevState => ({
      neededOnly: !prevState.neededOnly
    }));
/>
```

Comment: Oh yeah that should work thanks, do you have an idea if i want to remove just a few and not all of the not needed letters?

Comment: Just whatever letters you want to present should be in the neededLetters array. That way you can present whichever collection based on that toggle button.